# Word Cloud Arabic

Tags: python, python-3.x, word-cloud, wordcloud2

I had some problem with WordCloud code in python when try to run Arabic huge data
this my code:

```
from os import path
import codecs
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
d = path.dirname(__file__)
f = codecs.open(path.join(d, 'C:/example.txt'), 'r', 'utf-8')
text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(f.read())
text = get_display(text)
wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='arial',background_color='white', mode='RGB',width=1500,height=800).generate(text)
wordcloud.to_file("arabic_example.png")
```

And this is the error I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/aam20/Desktop/python/codes/WordClouds/wordcloud_True.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/aam20/Desktop/python/codes/WordClouds')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\aam20\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 705, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\aam20\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:/Users/aam20/Desktop/python/codes/WordClouds/wordcloud_True.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       text = get_display(text)
>
> File "C:\Users\aam20\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bidi\algorithm.py",
>   line 648, in get_display
>       resolve_implicit_levels(storage, debug)
>
> File "C:\Users\aam20\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bidi\algorithm.py",
>   line 466, in resolve_implicit_levels
>
> '%s not allowed here' % _ch['type']
>
> AssertionError: RLI not allowed here

Can someone help resolve this issue?

Comment: my  data is huge its about 17000 rows, can't run it,
but if i try to run a little data the code will run it without any error.
also I have another code that can run a huge data but with reflect words
I will attach the code with results

Comment: I add the complete error text to my question

Comment: If you look at the error message, the problem is not `wordcloud` but the `bidi` package as the error occurs in line `text = get_display(text)`; you never make it to the wordcloud execution. I suspect that there is some word with improperly encoded characters in your data set. If you truncate the data, you are excluding that word (or list of words).

Comment: On a related note, you should preprocess your text (tokenize, filter out common, non-specific words, etc) and select a much smaller subset of words that can actually be displayed in a readable font size.

Answer (score 5):

I tried to preprocess the text with the mentioned method below! before calling reshaper and it worked for me.

```
def removeWeirdChars(text):
    weirdPatterns = re.compile("["
                               u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
                               u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
                               u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
                               u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                               u"\U00002702-\U000027B0"
                               u"\U000024C2-\U0001F251"
                               u"\U0001f926-\U0001f937"
                               u'\U00010000-\U0010ffff'
                               u"\u200d"
                               u"\u2640-\u2642"
                               u"\u2600-\u2B55"
                               u"\u23cf"
                               u"\u23e9"
                               u"\u231a"
                               u"\u3030"
                               u"\ufe0f"
                               u"\u2069"
                               u"\u2066"
                               u"\u200c"
                               u"\u2068"
                               u"\u2067"
                               "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)
    return weirdPatterns.sub(r'', text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, so I removed the emoji than it work just fine

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import arabic_reshaper
import emoji

your_txt = emoji.replace_emoji(your_txt, replace='', version=-1)
your_txt = arabic_reshaper.reshape(your_txt)
your_txt = get_display(reshaped_text)
wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf').generate(your_txt)
wordcloud.to_file("ar_wordCloud.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a weird character in your text that `get_display()` is unable to deal with. You can find this character and add it to a list of stopwords. However it might be very painful. One shortcut is to create a dictionary with most frequent words and their frequencies and feed it to `generate_from_frequencies` fucnction:

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='arial',background_color='white', mode='RGB',width=1500,height=800).generate_from_frequencies(YOURDICT)
```

For more information check my response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60656343/in-wordcloud-on-python-i-would-like-to-merge-two-languages) post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can simply generate Arabic wordCloud:

```
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display


reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text)
bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf').generate(bidi_text)
wordcloud.to_file("worCloud.png")
```

And here is a link to Google colab example: [Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OmP1TOqXq8gCPNxlLCaKGWHNJ_q3dHRu?usp=sharing)